# SwiftyJSON Parse JSON error for array object

Tags: json, swift, xcode, swifty-json

I am retrieving data from URL like this:

```
let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
                let results = swiftyJSON[0]["name"]
                print(results)
            } else {
                print("error")
            }
        }
```

For the above, I get data like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "_id":"123",
      "_rev":"345",
      "name":"hey"
   },
   {  
      "_id":"133",
      "_rev":"33345",
      "name":"hello"
   }
]
```

I always end up in error block and I am not sure why?

I pasted the JSON in chrome console and able to do `swiftyJSON[0].name`. I would like to print all elements from the above json OBJECT.

Error:

```
error Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f87514ab570 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:3000/idea, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:3000/idea, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found.})
```

Please note, localhost:3000 is on.

Comment: The error is not about parsing the Json. It's about connecting to your local host.. Make sure the device is configured to the same port at your local host.

Answer (score 0):

The error you pasted may be the request's hostname not found.
"A server with the specified hostname could not be found." The JSON parse seems right totally.

Comment: are you running your app with simulator or the real iphone?

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the JSON data. The data cannot be retrieved in the first place since the URL `http://localhost:3000/idea` is not working.

Most likey, the URL is valid on your Mac but not on your iPhone. The URL would only be valid if your server side was running on the iPhone or simulator itself, which is rather unlikely.

`localhost` isn't a global address. On your Mac, it refers to your Mac. On an iPhone, it refers to the iPhone itself.

Open the Network Utility app on your Mac, look up the IP address and replace `localhost` with your IP address, e.g. `http://192.168.1.37:3000/idea`. Then your iOS app will be able to retrieve the data.